# Get a list of all dataframe names passed as arguments to a function

Tags: python, dataframe, arguments

I have created a function that joins all the dataframes via a left join and want it to be able to take a flexible number of arguments. The issue is that I need a list of all the dataframe names to use in the reduce function.So in the example below, I need all_dfs which is a list of all the arguments passed to the function. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
from functools import reduce
def myfunc(*args):
     result = reduce(
     lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=["p_key"], how="left"),
     all_dfs
     )
     return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name you're looking for is `args`.

Comment: args would return the dataframes themselves rather than the names of the dataframe

Comment: @user14128401 I don't think you understand how names work. Dataframes have no names. You can have names that point to DataFrames, or multiple names that point to the same DataFrame, but not the other way around.

Comment: @user14128401 does your code work when you use `args` instead of `all_dfs`?

Comment: ah yes thank you for that, it does work!